# Find all pairs of primes $(p, q)$, such that $p + q$ and $p + 4q$ are perfect squares.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Find all pairs of primes $(p, q)$, such that $p + q$ and $p + 4q$ are perfect squares.

Comment: Hint: Let $p+q = x^2$ and $p + 4q = y^2$. Subtract the first equation from the second, and then factor.

Comment: Things factor very nicely further on also.

Comment: If the second equation is replaced by $p +(r+1)q = y^2$ where $r$ is a prime, the only solutions are with $r=3$ and $p$ and $q$ as in my solution.

Comment: When posting a Question, it is common practice to add enough context (about your attempts and interest in the problem) for Readers to guess at what level of response you would be most benefitted.

Answer (score 2):

I get that the only solutions are
$p=13, q=3$
and
$p=5, q=11$.

If
$p+q = m^2$
and
$p+4q = n^2$
then,
subtracting,
$3q = n^2-m^2
=(n-m)(n+m)
$.

$3q$ can factor in
two ways:

$(1, 3q), (3, q)$.

If $n-m = 1,
n+m = 3q$
then
$n=m+1,
3q = n+m
= 2m+1$.

Then
$p = m^2-q
=m^2-(2m+1)/3
=\frac{3m^2-2m-1}{3}
=\frac{(3m+1)(m-1)}{3}
$.
Since
$3 \not\mid 3m+1$,
$3 | m-1$.
Since $p$ is prime,
we must have
$m = 4$
so
$p = 13$
and
$3q = 9$
so $q = 3$.

Check:
$p+q = 16$
and
$p+4q = 13+12 = 25$.

If $n-m = 3$,
then
$q = n+m
= 2m+3
$
so
$p = m^2-q
=m^2-2m-3
=(m+1)(m-3)
$.

Since this is prime,
$m-3 = 1$
so $m=4$
and
$p = m+1 = 5$.
$q = 2m+3
=11
$.

Check:
$p+q = 16,
p+4q = 5+44 = 49$.